# searching Problem

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator, cocos2d-iphone

i am fetching data from database ,and i am showing result on labels ,data is coming from one table, 
i want to search a specific word from the present table view ,,,
i want if the desired world is exist in the present table view then its clr should be change,

any one can help me :)(I am devlping app in Iphone)

Regards 
Haseeb

Comment: plz provide some code so that someone can help u....

Comment: i am using alertview to get query from the user , i am new to this envirment can you plez give me more specific idea abt it... thanx in advance - (IBAction) Search_hadit { NSString *msgTitle = @"Search in All Chapters"; UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:msgTitle message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Search", @"Cancel", nil]; [alert addTextFieldWithValue:@"" label:@"Query"]; [alert show]; [alert release]; } please give me a clear idea to do so..

Comment: Please add code clearly-formatted to your question ("edit") - its really hard readable now.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is that once you get the desired data from database (Which I guess can be an array)  call this method `[tableViewPtr reloadData]` and in the TableView Delegate Method.    `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` 
Here tableViewPtr is your outlet for tableview .Inside the delegate method search for the text string and If found you can either set a background image else update the cell accordingly

As you have mentioned that you are taking the input for search text using a Textfield in an alert view you can grab the input string from the alert View using somthing like this

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        searchString = myTextField.text;
        if(searchString)
        {
            [myTable reloadData];
        }
        [myTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Here myTextField is the textField that was added to the alertView

And In the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method you can compare this string with the content of the cell

```
if (searchString != nil)
{
        if([searchString caseInsensitiveCompare:currentCellText] == 0)
        {
            change the desired property for cell
        }
}
```

here myTextField is a TextField and searchString is an NSString declared in .h file

Comment: i am using alertview to get query from the user , i am new to this envirment can you plez give me more specific idea abt it... thanx in advance - (IBAction) Search_hadit { NSString *msgTitle = @"Search in All Chapters"; UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:msgTitle message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Search", @"Cancel", nil]; [alert addTextFieldWithValue:@"" label:@"Query"]; [alert show]; [alert release]; } please give me a clear idea to do so.

Comment: can to please .. brief bit more ?